# Attempt to get the last modified time of a file changes the timestamp

Tags: c, linux, posix

I'm trying to list all the elements in a directory, that is print the filenames and last data modification timestamps (in a readable format):

```
DIR* dir_stream;
/*Open directory*/
struct dirent* entry;
struct stat buf;
errno = 0;

for(entry = readdir(dir_stream); entry != NULL; entry = readdir(dir_stream)) {
    if(lstat(g_cwd, &buf) == -1) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Couldn't obtain info about %s\n%s\n", entry->d_name, strerror(errno));
        return -1;
    }

    printf("%s %s", entry->d_name, ctime(&buf.st_mtime));
    errno = 0;
}
/*Handle errors and close the stream*/
```

The output looks something like this:

```
prog Fri Nov 12 20:22:39 2021
f2 Fri Nov 12 20:22:39 2021
f3 Fri Nov 12 20:22:39 2021
Makefile Fri Nov 12 20:22:39 2021
```

The point is, the timestamps I get are all the same and equal to the time when the program was run. It seems like either `readdir()` or `lstat()` modify the value of `st_mtime` but I dont't see this behavior being mentioned in `man 3p readdir` or `man 3p lstat`. What may be causing the problem? And is there any way around it?

Comment: What kind of filesystem is it? It might not store modification times.

Comment: What is `g_cwd` used to obtain the file information?

Comment: You're not getting the status of the current file in the iteration, you're getting the status of `g_cwd`.

Comment: Since `g_cwd` doesn't change, you get the same result each time.

Comment: Was that the name of the directory you opened?

Comment: If `g_cwd` is the directory you're listing, you need to concatenate `entry->d_name` to it with `/` between them to get the pathname to stat.

Comment: Thanks @Barmar, problem solved!